# Scale background images using CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, image, carousel, scaling

I am using the following [Modern Business Template](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/modern-business/) from Startbootstrap.com and the homepage features a carousel.  When I set the background image using CSS attribute, `background-size: cover;`  It stretches image but is does not scale.  How do I stretch the image to cover the entire carousel panel and scales appropriately.

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('Content/img/myimage.jpg');"></div>
```

CSS:

```
header.carousel .fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size:     cover;                      
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: you could hav min height and width.

Answer (score 0):

In place on `background-fit: cover`, I believe what you're looking for is [**object-fit: cover**](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/). Like `background-fit: cover`, `object-fit: cover` allows the image to cover the full width of the parent, but doesn't scale the image, allowing it to maintain its aspect ratio.

```
header.carousel .fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;                   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Hope this helps! :)